# How to log out of Google external provider?

Tags: identityserver4

Right now I can log out of Identity Server. But when logging back in, I can just select my email address - without having to reenter my password - to log in though Google to access my app. 
I want to have to reenter my password (because the device is shared between multiple users). I followed the [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signout_external_providers.html), but I must be missing something.

(I am using a MVC client to test things out)
Here is the client's configuration:

```
  {
    "Enabled": true,
    "EnableLocalLogin": false,
    "ClientId": "backOffice.mvc",
    "ClientName": "BackOffice client",
    "ClientSecrets": [
      {
        "Value": "xxx"
      }
    ],
    "AllowedGrantTypes": [
      "hybrid"
    ],
    "AllowedScopes": [
      "openid",
      "offline_access",
      "profile"
    ],
    "RedirectUris": [
      "http://localhost:5098/signin-oidc"
    ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [
      "http://localhost:5098/"
    ],
    "RequireConsent": false,
    "AllowOfflineAccess": true
  }
```

And the provider settings:

```
                .AddOpenIdConnect("Google", "Google", options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
                    options.ForwardSignOut = IdentityServerConstants.DefaultCookieAuthenticationScheme;

                    options.Authority = "https://accounts.google.com/";

                    options.ClientId = Configuration["GoogleClientId"];

                    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-google";

                    options.Scope.Add("email");
                })
```

Thanks a lot for any help! And please let me know if you need more informations :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Google does not advertise an `end_session` endpoint via `https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration` so front-channel sign out is not an option.

However you may be able to provide an additional `prompt=login` parameter in the authorize endpoint request in an attempt to force interactive authentication. You can enforce this in your client by checking that the `auth_time` claim is suitably recent.